# MonoTouch.Dialog: Scroll Events

Tags: keyboard, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog, uitableview

Using MTD, I have created a `UITableViewDelegate` and attached it to the main `TableView`.

```java
this.TableView.Delegate = new MyTableDelegate();
```

However at no time do any of the events on the delegate fire.

My goal is to dismiss the Keyboard when the user scrolls the table. (I'm open to other options)

```java
//Never gets called
class MyTableDelegate:UITableViewDelegate
{
    public override void DraggingStarted(UIScrollView scrollView)
    {
        HideKeyboard();
    }
}
```